# My SSL setup fails in firefox

Tags: ssl-certificate, firefox

I have just started using firefox (from google chrome) and when I viewed my website, the ssl certificate appears to be invalid. Could anyone double check this https://www.centredegenetique.ca/secure.php. If it is invalid, how would I fix it. I am using starfield technologies certification with the intermediary certificate installed. It works under chrome and IE8. I do not understand the problem since Starfield certificate is installed by default on firefox. Anyone got pointers?

Comment: Doesn't work in safari for iPhone or iPad either. I'd suggest there is a problem with your intermediate cert here.

Comment: What version of FF are you using??

Comment: im using 3.6.11 firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me in Chrome-dev on Windows 7. Doesn't work in my firefox.

Is the root CA trusted by the guys who manage the firefox cert repo? Are you absolutely certain you've got the intermediary cert installed properly? Firefox doesn't see it...

Comment: The problem was that the intermediate certs line was commented out. It was correctly written however. So the problem was with the lack of intermediate cert.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in Firefox 4.0b8pre (prerelease build). Maybe they added the missing certificate in this version...